# Binding to a dependency property of a behavior inside a child control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following user control with a custom dependency property

**ThumbnailListView UserControl**

```
        <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Background="White" 
            SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"
            AllowDrop="True">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:DragDropBehavior OnDragDrop="{Binding Path=ItemDragDrop}"></behaviors:DragDropBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsLastListItem}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,20"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"></Setter>                      
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"></Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**Dependency Property ItemDragDrop of ThumbnailListView**

```
    public static ICommand GetItemDragDrop(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(ItemDragDropProperty);
    }

    public static void SetItemDragDrop(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ItemDragDropProperty, value);
    }

    public static DependencyProperty ItemDragDropProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemDragDrop",
        typeof(ICommand), typeof(ThumbnailListView));

    public ICommand ItemDragDrop
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(ItemDragDropProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemDragDropProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

**NewScansView UserControl**

```
        <DockPanel Dock="Top">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Scans}" Width="500">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
            <Views:ThumbnailListView DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem.Pages}" ItemDragDrop="{Binding SelectedItem.DragDropCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" />
            <Views:PageListView DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem.Pages}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DockPanel>
```

The NewScansView xaml contains a ThumbnailListView control and has bound the dependency property ItemDragDrop of the ThumbnailListView to a command in the class of SelectedItem.

Inside the ThumbnailListView user control I have a behavior DragDropBehavior which has a dependency property OnDragDrop.

I am trying to bind OnDragDrop to ItemDragDrop so that when a drag drop operation completes the command in the SelectedItem class is executed.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be able to find either the ItemDragDrop property on the ThumbnailListView or the DragDropCommand of the selected item class.

I'm wondering what i'm doing wrong and how I can set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThumbnailListView.DataContext` is set to `SelectedItem.Pages`, and I highly doubt that `SelectedItem.Pages` has a property called `SelectedItem.DragDropCommand`.

Change the `Source` of your `ItemDragDrop` binding to specify it uses something other than the `ThumnailListView.DataContext` for the source of that binding.

```
<DockPanel x:Name="MyDockPanel" Dock="Top">
    ...
    <Views:ThumbnailListView DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem.Pages}" 
                             ItemDragDrop="{Binding SelectedItem.DragDropCommand, ElementName=MyDockPanel}" ... />
    ...
</DockPanel>
```

You probably also have to do the same for your behavior binding - change the source of it so it points to the `ThumbnailListView` instead of to the `ThumbnailListView.DataContext`

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:DragDropBehavior OnDragDrop="{Binding Path=ItemDragDrop, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ThumbnailListView}}}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

---

Or better yet, either make a DependencyProperty for Pages so you don't rely on a specific `DataContext` object type

```
<Views:ThumbnailListView PagesDependencyProperty="{Binding SelectedItem.Pages}" ItemDragDrop="{Binding SelectedItem.DragDropCommand}" .. />
```

Or edit your control so it assumes a specific type is being used for the DataContext, and use an implicit DataTemplate to always draw that type of object using this control (far more common for me) :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" ...>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:DragDropBehavior OnDragDrop="{Binding DragDropCommand}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    ...
</ListView>
```

Implicit DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WhateverSelectedItemDataTypeIs}}">
    <!-- DataContext will automatically set to WhateverSelectedItemDataTypeIs -->
    <Views:ThumbnailListView /> 
</DataTemplate>
```

---